# Convert URLs into Regular Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i am using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll in asp.net for url re-writting, but i don't know about regular expressions. Is there anyone who could help me out convert these urls into regular expression.

```
http://localhost:50788/catalog.aspx?VendorID=1&CategoryID=1
```

VendorID could be changed as well as CategoryID.

```
http://localhost:50788/Product.aspx?ProductID=1
```

similarly ProductID could be changed.
I actually want to write regular expression for these query string in web.confg file such as

```
<!-- Rewrite department pages -->
    <rewrite url="/Index" to="~/Default.aspx" />
```

And One lastthing, is there any best url-rewriter other than this?.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert URLs to regular expression"?  Perhaps you should read up on what a regular expression is?

Comment: I mean, i need regular expression that could support URLs written (such as above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, and as others have pointed out. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
new Regex(@"http://localhost:50788/catalog\.aspx\?VendorID=\d+&CategoryID=\d+");

new Regex(@"http://localhost:50788/Product\.aspx\?ProductID=\d+");
```

Comment: I am actually trying to write regular expression in web.confg file such as       <rewrite url="/Index" to="~/Default.aspx" />